# No job functions found, migrating to .net 8 isolated worker process

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-8.0

I am following the migration [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net8) for migrating Azure Functions app to run in an isolated worker process in .Net 8 . However when I run the application it doesn't list any of the functions like it did when I was running it in .net 6 .

from console:

```
 No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. 
    > [2023-11-23T22:50:37.771Z] 0 functions found (Host)
    > [2023-11-23T22:50:37.772Z] Reading functions metadata (Custom)
    > [2023-11-23T22:50:37.772Z] 1 functions found (Custom)
    > [2023-11-23T22:50:37.772Z] 0 functions loaded
```

Program.cs

```
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
    ...
    })
.Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Is something missing in program.cs?

Comment: you forgot to add 
`)
.Build();`  In your `program.cs`. As mentiond in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net8#programcs-file)

Comment: forgot it in the code sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used code mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/migrate-dotnet-to-isolated-model?tabs=net8#programcs-file) and it worked for me.

Make sure to install `.NET 8.0`, latest `packages` as per requirement and upgrade to latest `Azure Function core tools` for local run from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows,in-process,node-v4,python-v2,http-trigger,container-apps&pivots=programming-language-csharp#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools)

I am using HTTP Trigger

**#My Code:**
**`.csproj`:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>My.Namespace</RootNamespace>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
    <!-- Other packages may also be in this list -->
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`program.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

**`HttpTrigger`:**

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public class HttpTrigger1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public HttpTrigger1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HttpTrigger1>();
        }

        [Function("HttpTrigger1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Function!");
        }
    }
}
```

**`local.settings.json`:**

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]

[image]

**Azure:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was also missing isolated from "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"

Comment: "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated" wasn't added by the VS .NET 8 migration tool, but fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, please do the following in Azure Portal:

- Change to .NET 8 Isolated
- Change platform to 64 bits

[image: Configuration in Azure Portal]

If you want to apply these new settings on bicep, please refer to this sample code that adds:

`use32BitWorkerProcess: false`
`netFrameworkVersion: 'v8.0'`

```json
// Function App
resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-09-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned, UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${msiRbacId}': {}
    }
  }
  kind: 'functionapp'
  properties: {
    keyVaultReferenceIdentity: msiRbacId
    enabled: true
    hostNameSslStates: [
      {
        name: '${functionAppName}.azurewebsites.net'
        sslState: 'Disabled'
        hostType: 'Standard'
      }
      {
        name: '${functionAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net'
        sslState: 'Disabled'
        hostType: 'Standard'
      }
    ]
    serverFarmId: appService.id
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: union(secretsMap, [
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: '@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=${keyVault.name};SecretName=${storageAccount.name}-${appInternalServiceName}-ConnectionString)'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: '@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=${keyVault.name};SecretName=${storageAccount.name}-${appInternalServiceName}-ConnectionString)'
        }
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: appInsightsInstrumentationKey
        }
        {
          name: 'APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING'
          value: 'InstrumentationKey=${appInsightsInstrumentationKey}'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: functionRuntime
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~4'
        }
      ])
      use32BitWorkerProcess: false
      netFrameworkVersion: 'v8.0'
      
    }
    scmSiteAlsoStopped: false
    clientAffinityEnabled: false
    clientCertEnabled: false
    hostNamesDisabled: false
    dailyMemoryTimeQuota: 0
    httpsOnly: false
    redundancyMode: 'None'
  
  }
  tags: appTags
}
```